# Failed to persist profile to underlying stores

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, commerce-server

I have completed the Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 setup. When I try to register a user on the live site, it shows this error on page:

> Failed to persist profile to underlying stores

I have verified the columns of the `UserObject` table in the `Profiles` database with that of a working environment. They are the same.

When I check the `User Manager` in the CMS, the new user details are displayed there, but they are not present in the `Customer & Order Manager`.

Here is the log:

```
7296 15:33:39 ERROR Register failed
Exception: CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.Profiles.CommerceProfileSystemException
Message: Failed to persist profile to underlying stores.
Source: CommerceServer.Core.Runtime
   at CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.Profiles.Profile.Update()
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Profiles.CommerceServerProfileProvider.GetUserProfile(String userName)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Profiles.CommerceServerProfileProvider.SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection collection)
   at Sitecore.Security.SwitchingProfileProvider.SetPropertyValues(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyValueCollection collection)
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.SaveCore()
   at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.Save()
   at System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.SaveWithAssert()
   at System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.Save()
   at Sitecore.Security.UserProfile.Save()
   at Sitecore.Security.SecurityUtil.SetUserDigestCredentials(User user, String credentials, String credentialsWithoutDomain)
   at Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email)
   at Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Create(String userName, String password)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Data.Customers.SitecoreUserRepository.Create(CommerceUser entity, String password)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Pipelines.Customers.CreateUser.CreateUserInSitecore.CreateUser(CreateUserRequest request, CreateUserResult result)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.Services.ServiceProvider.RunPipeline[TRequest,TResult](String pipelineName, TRequest request)
   at Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Website.Managers.AccountManager.RegisterUser(RegisterUserInputModel inputModel) in D:\Projects\External\TARH\Code\DCRMarketing\sitecore.demo.retail\src\Foundation\Commerce\Website\Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Website\Managers\AccountManager.cs:line 250
   at Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Customers.Website.Controllers.CustomersController.Register(RegisterUserInputModel inputModel) in D:\Projects\External\TARH\Code\DCRMarketing\sitecore.demo.retail\src\Feature\Customers\Website\Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Customers.Website\Controllers\CustomersController.cs:line 190

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E2F
Source: CommerceServer.Core.Interop
   at CommerceServer.Core.Interop.Profiles.IProfileObject2.Update()
   at CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.Profiles.Profile.Update()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your profile and/or encryption might not be set up properly.

Please check and optionally re-run these steps from the [Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 Deployment Guide](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DeploymentGuide/en-us/index.html#Concepts/c_SC_SetUpCommerceServerSite.html).
`

```
ProfileKeyManager.exe /kn /o "c:\profileEncryptionKeys.xml" /f
```

and

```
ProfileKeyManager.exe /ke /kf "c:\profileEncryptionKeys.xml" /reg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CommerceServer\Encryption\Keys\CFSolutionStorefrontSite /f
```

and finally

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:".\Database\Profiles\Commerce.Storefront.ProfileDatabase.dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:CFSolutionStorefrontSite_profiles /TargetServerName:"127.0.0.1"
```

Full information in the linked guide.

*edited to add*

[This accepted answer from Community Forums](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/6/t/2813). It is for Sitecore Commerce 9, but I think the underlying problem is the same.

Comment: I have checked this article and stuck at step 5 & 6.
http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SCpbCS81/SCpbCSRefSfGuide/en-us/GenerateProfileEncryptionKeys.html#concept_ybq_dlc_kt

I am looking at a working instance's showconfig.aspx & also its web.config and do not find the `encryption` or `profilewebservices` nodes in them. We are using Sitecore 8.2 u5. Could you pls advise where to include those settings.

Comment: You can check if the registry path in `Website\App_Config\CommerceServer.Core.config` is the same as the one you give on step 2 above - then check registry that there is indeed a profile encryption key defined